# As a MongoDB DBA, what do I need to know about the meltdown/spectre vulnerabilities?

Tags: mongodb, patching

If you didn't hear, a set of related vulnerabilities were recently discovered that impact virtually all processors sold over the last decade. [You can find more technical detail about the meltdown/spectre vulnerabilities on InfoSec.SE.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176803/meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities)

**As a MongoDB DBA, what do I need to understand about this?**

What are the potential performance impacts? What are the proper patching guide lines? What are cloud providers doing in regards to this vulnerability?

**Related Questions:**

- [As a MS SQL DBA, what do I need to know about the meltdown/spectre vulnerabilities?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194751/as-a-ms-sql-dba-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabiliti)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An official response from Mongo on 1/6/2018 (emphasis mine):

> Recently disclosed research regarding security vulnerabilities in
>   almost all modern processors such as Intel and AMD (CVE-2017-5715,
>   CVE-2017-5753, and CVE-2017-5754) has prompted public and private
>   institutions, including cloud providers, to patch OS and hypervisor
>   infrastructures. These patches disable performance optimizing features
>   of CPUs, and it is expected that, regardless of OS or cloud provider,
>   all workloads will see a performance impact. We are investigating the
>   performance implications of these patches to MongoDB on both OS
>   kernels as well as cloud hypervisors.
>
> #### Hypervisor Patch Impact
>
> As a result of the patches applied by AWS
>   between January 3rd and January 5th, 2017, we have observed the
>   following:
>
> **For high-load benchmarks (e.g. YCSB) we measured a 10-15% impact on
>   throughput with some exceptional cases that are still being studied.**
>   We believe these results are consistent with other industry research.
>   We will release additional results (including additional cloud
>   providers) in the coming days.
>
> #### Kernel Patch Impact
>
> This is the impact that customers can expect to
>   see when they apply the recommended patches to their cloud VMs or
>   on-premises hardware:
>
> **At this time we have not seen a substantial signal (either better or
>   worse) on major distributions such as Amazon Linux, Red Hat Enterprise
>   Linux, and Ubuntu.** Based on the industry research we expect that there
>   will be some measurable performance impact (although yet to be
>   quantified). We will have additional results made available in the
>   coming days. If you have any questions or concerns, please file a
>   ticket in the [Support Portal](https://clicktime.symantec.com/a/1/8AqhO-AqDm0sT-SmzCvq17PQ9zY4JfmxR8h08a6S9_4=?d=xWnWyqZqIjIHWs8W-UmHrg0hOMDDP1n88ErkTf6Ek3bc7_wv86UoTi5FonKSHm35zryTh6QCUMGyY2LQhu2ppJap8tTrl3a59Ln1A3OLorehQzFDaO8bXfE1Aey1POZ_lOcJ3QeuwAiekXOEepe-qyNDlKO8PF--sms6vBdbvnx2Bu54GQc2R83xiJtZLuQYLi94hM0jNPx7iqDraYr_c1czCQlujoE9EDF1Ys0cAZqRYHzJL5gCZ9LMLz4tmoyJyveK9Fn8G5N9sNPxASyOSfPXaQne-uWPi6kZyiu7_yVcra9QujNRg5OnbAVIErEHwb8Sc2_O7XFg9w5p_xqTrVI0MpERfs8V52eHhiJjPDgklRRBqsCbnvgTZOlNs-JvzkDI6HExseqV0UNNuqlPn_Jw0uKdm0k2hmpAABPdI7WzB5SksA%3D%3D&u=http%3A%2F%2Fapp.go.mongodb.com%2Fe%2Fer%3Futm_campaign%3DInt_EM_Intel%20Critical%20Advisory_01_18_WW%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_source%3DEloqua%26s%3D413370795%26lid%3D4959%26elqTrackId%3D6bf9737ed1ec4d2abebc3b6e1490bb4e%26elq%3Da0dfe62d498749d3be3a8dbc391d7854%26elqaid%3D5772%26elqat%3D1).
>
> You can read [Intel’s white paper](https://clicktime.symantec.com/a/1/t2iwWvoiRx9ECzSr2Lh9X5p6saVAz9BMV3c37MFCdYc=?d=xWnWyqZqIjIHWs8W-UmHrg0hOMDDP1n88ErkTf6Ek3bc7_wv86UoTi5FonKSHm35zryTh6QCUMGyY2LQhu2ppJap8tTrl3a59Ln1A3OLorehQzFDaO8bXfE1Aey1POZ_lOcJ3QeuwAiekXOEepe-qyNDlKO8PF--sms6vBdbvnx2Bu54GQc2R83xiJtZLuQYLi94hM0jNPx7iqDraYr_c1czCQlujoE9EDF1Ys0cAZqRYHzJL5gCZ9LMLz4tmoyJyveK9Fn8G5N9sNPxASyOSfPXaQne-uWPi6kZyiu7_yVcra9QujNRg5OnbAVIErEHwb8Sc2_O7XFg9w5p_xqTrVI0MpERfs8V52eHhiJjPDgklRRBqsCbnvgTZOlNs-JvzkDI6HExseqV0UNNuqlPn_Jw0uKdm0k2hmpAABPdI7WzB5SksA%3D%3D&u=http%3A%2F%2Fapp.go.mongodb.com%2Fe%2Fer%3Futm_campaign%3DInt_EM_Intel%20Critical%20Advisory_01_18_WW%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_source%3DEloqua%26s%3D413370795%26lid%3D4958%26elqTrackId%3Da766d0ff748c4959b99c1a91b6ddf442%26elq%3Da0dfe62d498749d3be3a8dbc391d7854%26elqaid%3D5772%26elqat%3D1) to learn more about these
>   vulnerabilities.

---

Related Posts:

- Glenn Berry: [Checking your Meltdown and Spectre Mitigation Status in Windows](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/checking-your-meltdown-and-spectre-mitigation-status-in-windows/)

Comment: Here are more details of the performance impact of the Meltdown/Spectre patch for MongoDB on AWS/Azure/Digital - https://scalegrid.io/blog/meltdown-performance-impact-on-mongodb-aws-azure-digitalocean/